# Where is the line `xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"` works/needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recommended way of integrating angularjs into html [looks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="angular.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

The question is: none of the textbooks uses `xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"` line. Where is that important or make sense?
Should the line to be used with every module declaration?

Comment: this mainly just for manually bootstrapping angular when you can't use ng-app (i.e. older browsers)

Comment: older than which one?

Comment: Mainly IE < 9, see `Internet Explorer compatibility` on the link you posted (bottom of left rail)

Comment: i see, should this line to be used with every module declaration?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> If you choose to use the old style directive syntax ng: then include
>   xml-namespace in html to make IE happy. (This is here for historical
>   reasons, and we no longer recommend use of ng:.)

You can see more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This is not for manually bootstrapping angular, this is for automatically bootstrapping angular.  The xmlns namespace isn't necessary but probably good practice as it identifies the HTML page as using angular JS and is part of the current automatic initialization documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

At the same time, angular no longer recommends using the XML namespacing way of accessing its elements "ng:" (prefer ng- or data-ng-), so the namespace is not really being used in practice anymore.  Still can't hurt to leave it as an identifier.